# Ruby Actions: How to avoid a bunch of returns to halt execution?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry, actionview

How can I DRY the code below? Do I have to setup a bunch of ELSEs ? I usually find the "if this is met, stop", "if this is met, stop", rather than a bunch of nested ifs.

I discovered that redirect_to and render don't stop the action execution...

```
def payment_confirmed    
  confirm_payment do |confirmation|    
    @purchase = Purchase.find(confirmation.order_id)
    unless @purchase.products_match_order_products?(confirmation.products)
      # TODO notify the buyer of problems
      return
    end

    if confirmation.status == :completed
      @purchase.paid!                     
      # TODO notify the user of completed purchase
      redirect_to purchase_path(@purchase)
    else      
      # TODO notify the user somehow that thigns are pending
    end   

    return
  end

  unless session[:last_purchase_id]
    flash[:notice] = 'Unable to identify purchase from session data.'
    redirect_to user_path(current_user) 
    return
  end

  @purchase = Purchase.find(session[:last_purchase_id]) 

  if @purchase.paid?
    redirect_to purchase_path(@purchase)       
    return
  end

  # going to show message about pending payment
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following to reduce the code.

1) Use

```
return redirect_to(..)
```

instead of

```
redirect_to(..)
return
```

2) Extract the `flash` and `redirect_to` code to a common method.

```
def payment_confirmed    
  confirm_payment do |confirmation|    
    @purchase = Purchase.find(confirmation.order_id)        
    return redirect_with_flash(...) unless @purchase.products_match_..(..)

    return redirect_with_flash(...) unless confirmation.status == :completed

    @purchase.paid! 
    return redirect_to(...)
  end

  return redirect_with_flash(...) unless session[:last_purchase_id]      

  @purchase = Purchase.find(session[:last_purchase_id]) 
  return redirect_to(...) if @purchase.paid?

  # going to show message about pending payment
end
```

Create a new method to redirect to a given url after showing a flash message.

```
def redirect_with_flash url, message
  flash[:notice] = message
  redirect_to(url)
end
```

**Note** I have truncated the code above in some places for readability.

Comment: Hi Kandada. Think the code can be refactored to avoid returning early?

Comment: Combining `return` and `redirect_to` already reduces redundancy. Can you give more details in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Add `and return false` to the end of a redirect_to or render to halt execution at that point. That should help clean things up for you.

Comment: returning false causes Rails to render nothign?

Answer (score 0):

You could also factor out the steps into seperate methods. So the ending code would look something like:

```
def payment_confirmed    
  confirm_payment do |cnf|    
    confirmation_is_sane?(cnf) && purchase_done?(cnf)
    return
  end
  has_last_purchase? && last_purchase_paid?
end
```

For a factoring looking like:

```
def confirmation_is_sane?(confirmation)
   @purchase = Purchase.find(confirmation.order_id)
   unless @purchase.products_match_order_products?(confirmation.products)
     # TODO notify the buyer of problems and render
      return false 
    end
   true
end 
def purchase_done?(confirmation)
   if confirmation.status == :completed
      @purchase.paid!                     
      # TODO notify the user of completed purchase
      redirect_to purchase_path(@purchase)
      return false
    else      
      # TODO notify the user somehow that thigns are pending and render
      return true
    end   
end
def has_last_purchase?
  unless session[:last_purchase_id]
    flash[:notice] = 'Unable to identify purchase from session data.'
    redirect_to user_path(current_user) 
    return false
  end

  @purchase = Purchase.find(session[:last_purchase_id]) 
  return true
end
def last_purchase_paid?
  if @purchase.paid?
    redirect_to purchase_path(@purchase)       
    return false
  end
  # going to show message about pending payment
  return true
end
```

This is basically just using true/falses with &&'s to do the early exiting rather than using return, but it seems to read easier, to me. You'd still have to call `render` in the other methods, but that shouldn't be too big of a deal.

The distinction between the confirmation order and the last purchase seems strange as well, but perhaps this is an artifact of the way confirm_payment works.